# How to send a slack notification after ArgoCD post sync job completed

Tags: kubernetes, slack, argocd, argocd-notification

Our company uses ArgoCD to deploy DNS filter server applications. After deploy and synced in ArgoCD, a post sync job that contains regression tests will run.

So how to create a notification to send to slack channel after the regression tests either passed or failed?